# A struct for each child process and accessing the members

Tags: c, struct, fork, parent-child, child-process

So I'm forking a couple of child processes and each of them is supposed to take a line that I've read from a file and do operations on them.

What I have is a struct containing the lines like :

```
struct query { 
char lines[LINESIZE];
};
```

and I have an array of structs. So each struct serves to one child process.

This is how I forked my child processes :

```
 for(i=0; i<5; i++) { 
        n = fork();
    }
```

And say I have five structs to serve for each of these processes.

```
struct query query[5];
```

So First processes takes query[0].lines and do some operations on it, second process gets query[1].lines and does the same operations on it and so on ...

Should I use pipe to pass values between processes? I feel like there's a much simpler solution to this but my lack of practice and knowledge in C is really slowing me down.

Comment: Your question is not much clear. What is your exact purpose , is it just reading or doing some interprocess communication ? Be clear

Comment: For the child processes? A text file with a few lines of text in it is read by the program and I spawn a new process for each line in the text file. Then, each child process performs operations with the information given which is the line read from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to spawn 5 processes, but in the code that you posted you'll end up creating way more than 5 processes, in fact in:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  n = fork();
}
```

when i = 0 you'll fork a process, since the forked process is an exact copy of the parent it will continue in the for loop, so at that point you'll have two processes each one having i = 1 and forking each one a new process, then you'll have at this point 4 processes, when the loop is complete you have created 160 processes.

Allocating and initializing the array "query" before the forking it is perfectly fine what you have to fix is the spawning. The fork() call returns 0 in the child process, the process id of the child to the parent process or -1 if there was a error. Knowing if the current process is the parent or the child we can continue or break out of the loop and do the computation:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  if(fork() == 0) {
    /* child process */
    process_query(query[i]);
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: You did not answer the second part regarding the use of pipes as was asked

Comment: Well, unless the children processes have to communicate back to the parent in this case it isn't needed to use pipes.

Comment: I do have the error checking for fork but just didn't include them in the question.

Comment: But you were right about correcting spawning of children. I didn't have the for loop implemented correctly.